# Ejecutar MYSQL en un script de tipo bash

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, ubuntu, bash

Saludos comunidad espero que estén bien.

Tengo un problema, quiero ejecutar unas cuantas sentencias de MYSQL pero a modo de `BASH`, necesito ejecutar esto en ubuntu.

Yo he creado un archivo llamado `scripts.sh` donde he colocado las sentencias a ejecutar:

```
  #!/bin/bash   
  mysql -u Prueba -p123456 <<EOF 
  use BDPrueba; 
  delete from positions where servertime between '2017-09-01' and '2017-09-30';  
  EOF
```

El problema es que cuando intento ejecutar esto, me dice:

"No such file or directory"

Viendo que tengo otros scripts de tipo bash para otras operaciones, decidi probar cambiando el #!/bin/bash por #!/bin/sh y cuando lo hice me dice:

"Can't open"

Ya la verdad he leido miles de foros y miles de formas, pero la verdad es que veo que la forma de hacerlo es como lo he hecho. Espero me puedan ayudar a ver que está mal.

Gracias.

Comment: puedes hacer `mysql -u Prueba -p123456 BDPrueba  -e "delete from positions where servertime between '2017-09-01' and '2017-09-30';"` > log.txt

Answer (score 6):

El problema aquí es que estás intentando correr comandos de mysql pero en bash.

En la primera línea de tu script pones:

```
mysql -u Prueba -p123456 <<EOF
```

Con lo que me imagino que estás pensando que ahora los siguientes comandos serían ejecutados dentro de la consola de `mysql`, lo cual es algo incorrecto.

Los comandos `bash` o `sh` solo ejecutan aquellos comandos que se pueden correr en tu terminal, y no dentro de otras aplicaciones, para esto las aplicaciones deben ofrecer una manera de ejecutar estos comandos desde terminal, y el mysql client lo ofrece:

```
mysql --user="Prueba" --password="123456" --database="BDPrueba" --execute="delete from positions where servertime between '2017-09-01' and '2017-09-30';"
```

Answer (score 4):

Creo que hay una problema con los permisos. Necesita `chmod +x escripta.sh` a accessir y ejecutar el script.

Pero, a usar mySQL sentencias en un bash script, creo que debe escribir las sentencias en un otra lado.

Para ejempo

**ejemplo.sql**

```
use BDPrueba; 
delete from positions where servertime between '2017-09-01' and '2017-09-30';
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh 
mysql -u Prueba -p 123456 BDPrueba < ejemplo.sql
```

**E**

Y a usar el script, necesita escribir el comand en el terminal como esta:

`./script.sh`

Comment: Voy a probar con escribir las sentencias en otro lado, los permisos los tengo

Comment: Hice lo que me recoemndastes pero me da el mismo error. No such file or directory

Comment: ¿Como esta empazando el guión? Tiene que usar `./` voy a actualizar.

Comment: Si claro ./ tal cual

Comment: agregaria que significa el `<` en la stentencia

Answer (score 0):

Si te menciona el error de "No such file or directory" es tal cual, porque tu interprete de shell no encuentra el archivo o directorio que escribiste.

Si tu pones algo como:

```
$ mi_programa
```

Antes de que se ejecute un comando, se lleva a cabo una redirección (con "<" o ">"). Luego siguiendo la secuencia utilizada por la shell, que es esta.

1. Busca el alias.
2. Expansión de parámetros, sustitución de comandos, expansión aritmética y eliminación de comillas antes de ser asignados a la variable.
3. Revisa si es una función de shell `mi_programa(){...}`
4. Revisa si es un BUILTIN.
5. Revisa si está en las *hash tables*. `hash | less`
6. Revisa en la variable PATH (si no encuentra elementos de ruta en su el nombre del comando)

Si todo falla, aparece el mensaje de error del estilo "comando no encontrado", que parece ser que es el error que te aparece a tí.

Ahora, si nos centramos en el punto 6 del orden de ejecución, tienes que tener tu comando (o un enlace simbólico) `mi_programa` en una carpeta en la variable `PATH` (revisa con `echo $PATH`) siempre y cuando **este comando no tenga elementos de ruta**, los cuales son '/', '.', '..'. Si tiene elementos de ruta, busca en esa ruta, por ejemplo.

```
$ ls -la 
rwxrwxrwx 1 u1 u1 512 Nov 24 19:27 .
rwxrwxrwx 1 u1 u1 512 Nov 24 19:27 ..
rwxrwxrwx 1 u1 u1 512 Nov 24 19:27 mi_programa
$ pwd
/home/u1/carpeta1
$ /home/u1/carpeta1/mi_programa
(se ejecuta lo que tenga tu programa)
```

En este caso, ejecutaste tu programa porque lo escribiste con los elementos de ruta que son las diagonales '/'.

Ahora, en el caso de que uses los elementos de ruta como el punto '.' o los dos puntos '..' que son nombres que están enlazados con enlaces duros a la propia carpeta y a su ancestro, respectivamente. En otras palabras simplistas, '.' se refiere a la carpeta actual y '..' a su ancestro. Entonces puedes ejecutar de la misma manera tu programa con

```
$ ./mi_programa
```

O con.

```
$ ../carpeta1/miprograma
```

Tendrían que ejecutarte lo mismo.

Con estas dos cosas debería bastar para arreglar este problema, pero tenía que explicar antes todo el preámbulo para explicar el por qué del mensaje de error.

Todo esto es suponiendo que tienen permisos de ejecución. Es decir, si al escribir `ls` a mi_programa, tiene algo del estilo.

```
$ ls -la mi_programa
-r-xr-xr-x 1 u1 u1  25 Dec 18 21:59 mi_programa
# Con "r" de permisos de lectura (read) para que la shell lo pueda leer y con
# "x" de permisos de ejecución para que tu shell pueda permitir utilizarlo como
# ejecutable.
```

En caso de que no tenga permisos, puedes usar algo de alguna de las formas.

```
$ chmod a+x mi_programa
$ chmod u+x mi_programa
$ chmod +x mi_programa
$ chmod 755 mi_programa
```

Pero dudo que tenga este problema sino te daría un error de tipo "permiso denegado", más no "archivo no encontrado".

#### Aclaración con el *shebang*

Lo que hiciste de cambiar el *shebang* sólo cambiaste el programa con el que ejecutaría ese programa la shell.

Es decir, al poner la primera línea `#!/programa` indicas a la shell con qué programa vas a ejecutar el contenido de ese archivo.

Por ejemplo. Supongamos que tienes los archivos a1 y a2 en la misma carpeta, a2 tiene como contenido.

```
contenido
de archivo a2
```

Y en a1 tienes esto.

```
#!/bin/cat a2
```

Modificando los permisos para que se ejecute.

```
$ chmod u+x a1
$ ./a1
contenido
de archivo a2
#!/bin/cat a2
```

Aquí, con el *shebang* de `#!/bin/cat` hiciste uso del programa cat. En cambio, en el caso de bash o sh, haces uso de `/bin/bash` y de `/bin/dash`, así es `dash`, no es un typo.

En otras palabras, cambiarle el *shebang* a tu programa, no afecta nada si el error que te arroja es del estilo "No such file or directory".